# I u have upgrade the Android Studio 3.0.1 and getting many errors and execution failed

Tags: android

```
Android\stripe\res\drawable\ic_unknown.xml : Can't process attribute 
android:fillColor="@android:color/white": references to other resources 
are not supported by build-time PNG generation.
```

Comment: is your Android SDK location configure correctly ?

Comment: use tint in place of fillColor

Answer (score 2):

I face some similar problem after upgrading android studio , Solution to the problem is to give color code directly instead of giving reference to color code in vector assets

In your case instead of giving

`android:fillColor="@android:color/white"`

use

`android:fillColor="#ffffff"`

Answer (score 0):

Use hex code directly

```
<vector<path
android:fillColor="#FFF"/></vector>
```

Comment: or you can use tint , android 3.0 support tint instead of fillcolor